# is there was way to copy user meta to other table?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

i am looking for  wp user meta value copy to new table.

i.e.
wp_usermeta  have Billing_phone value i want to copy billing_phone value to other table i.e. wp_users column user_mobile.

how can i do it with old user's and upcoming new users mobile field update?

any help was respected.

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663137/add-new-column-in-wp-user-table

Comment: My Question was different. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the WordPress table structure, can you provide the table structure of the two tables and show how the fields you want to copy relate to each other?